# Run ansible as root with specific sudoers

Tags: ssh, ansible, sudo, sudoers

My issue is that I have one server where the `sudoers` for the **ansible user** is like this:

`ansible ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/su - root`

Hence, the only way to switch to the root user is:

`sudo su - root`

---

When I try to run the below ansible playbook:

```
---
- name: Configure Local Repo server address
  hosts: lab
  remote_user: ansible
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  become_method: runas
    
  tasks:
    - name: test whoami
      become: yes
      shell:
        cmd: whoami
      register: whoami_output
    - debug: var=whoami_output
    
    - name: Deploy local.repo file to the hosts
      become: yes
      copy:
        src: /etc/ansible/files/local.repo
        dest: /etc/yum.repos.d/local.repo
        owner: ansible
        group: ansible
        mode: 0644
        backup: yes
      register: deploy_file_output
    - debug: var=deploy_file_output
```

I got the following error:

`ansible-playbook --private-key /etc/ansible/keys/ansible_key /etc/ansible/playbooks/local_repo_provisioning.yml`

```
PLAY [Configure Local Repo server address] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.175.65.12]

TASK [test whoami] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [10.175.65.12]

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.175.65.12] => {
    "whoami_output": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": "whoami",
        "delta": "0:00:00.003301",
        "end": "2023-01-15 17:53:56.312715",
        "failed": false,
        "msg": "",
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2023-01-15 17:53:56.309414",
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "ansible",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "ansible"
        ]
    }
}

TASK [Deploy local.repo file to the hosts] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [10.175.65.12]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "checksum": "2356deb90d20d5f31351c719614d5b5760ab967d", "msg": "Destination /etc/yum.repos.d not writable"}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
10.175.65.12               : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

When I tried to use `become_method: sudo` I got the **"Missing sudo password"** message. Further, when I tried `become_method: su` I got the **"Timeout (12s) waiting for privilege escalation prompt:"** message.

---

All in all, would someone know how to explain how ansible runs the commands deppending on the "become_method" set? Is there a way to switch to the root user with that kind of sudoers conf?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what are the permissions of the `/etc/yum.repos.d` directory? based on the error message that seems to be the issue

Comment: Follows the `ls -lh` output:

`drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     56 Apr 19  2022 yum.repos.d`.

Hence, a root user should be able to write on it.

Comment: [Escalation method can't be chained](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_privilege_escalation.html#only-one-method-may-be-enabled-per-host) and [Privilege escalation must be general](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_privilege_escalation.html#privilege-escalation-must-be-general). These are known limitations by design. If this is not acceptable in your environment, don't use privilege escalation.

Comment: So the `sudoers` conf is the issue here?

>Methods cannot be chained. You cannot use sudo /bin/su - to become a user, you need to have privileges to run the command as that user in sudo or be able to su directly to it.

I can change to the root user with `sudo su - root`. I didn't understand it yet.

Comment: method `sudo` basically needs a line like this in sudoers: `ansibleuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`

Comment: Yes, I couldn't make it work with the `ansible ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/su - root` sudoers no matter what.